# I'm trying to learn to to request, load and parse Json data from API. I'm getting a value error

Tags: python, json, api

I've been trying to learn to retrieve Json data from an API, before parsing and writing to CSV. I've tried a number of methods, however I keep getting stuck at the first hurdle. With the code below, I get an expecting value error when trying to retrieve the data from URL. What am I missing?

Code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import pprint
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base_url="https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0001627475.json"
first_response=requests.get(base_url)
response_list=first_response.json()
```

Error message

```
        JSONDecodeError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-10ae360550df> in <module>
      1 base_url="https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0001627475.json"
      2 first_response=requests.get(base_url)
----> 3 response_list=first_response.json()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    898                     # used.
    899                     pass
--> 900         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    901 
    902     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358     if cls is None:
    359         cls = JSONDecoder

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: For me, the request returns `403 Forbiden`. Check the `first_response.status_code`.

Comment: And if you check `first_response.text` you'll see the HTML explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some requests are successful and others are not, so you can try:

```py
import requests
import json

base_url = "https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0001627475.json"

succeed = False

while not succeed:
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    try:
        dict_response = json.loads(response.text)
        succeed = True
    except:
        pass
```